# Inject beans с разными Scope

Tags: spring, bean-validation

Есть ли какие нибудь ограничения или правила использования бинами друг-друга с разными scope.

- singleton, prototype, request, session, globalSession.

Например у меня есть бин singleton, могу ли я заинжектить в него бин с session и как это будет работать?

Comment: Если proxy-классы бинов создаются с помощью cglib, то можете.

Comment: спасибо. почитаю про это. а есть какая нибудь статья или документация на этот счет. я гуглил но видел только аналогичные моему вопросы но внятного ответа не нашел.